# Can't access properties of "2d" objects via tiles[i-1] like I can of standard objects (javascript)

Tags: javascript, object, canvas, dynamic

I'm trying to build a random map generator using a grid of tiles in a canvas. For each tile `tiles[i]`, I check properties of the tile before using `tiles[i-1]`. This seems to work using "ordinary" objects (method 1), but not "2d" objects (method 2), where `tiles[i-1].tileID` appears as `tiles[i].tileID`.

```
for (i=0; i<40; i++) {
  tiles[i] = { tileID: i}; // METHOD 1
  tiles[i]=c.getContext("2d") // METHOD 2
  tiles[i].tileID = i // METHOD 2
  if(i>0) {
    console.log("my tile ID is", tiles[i].tileID,
    ". The tile ID of the tile before me is", tiles[i-1].tileID)
  }
}
```

Using method 1 (and deleting the two lines of method 2), the console prints what you'd expect:
*my tile ID is 12 . The tile ID of the tile before me is 11*

but not for method 2:
*my tile ID is 12 . The tile ID of the tile before me is 12*

Is there a reason for this (or some other way of doing it I should be adopting) before I look at workarounds? Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `c.getContext("2d")` always returns the same object. So when you do it like this:

```
for (i=0; i<40; i++) {
  tiles[i]=c.getContext("2d") // METHOD 2
  tiles[i].tileID = i // METHOD 2
}
```

Expression `tiles[i] = c.getContext("2d")` assigns the same object to each tile in array. Expression `tiles[i].tileID = i` is needed to assign a new id to tile object, but tile object always the same. And the same object just get a new ID in each iteration.

The right way to save properties in tile is to make new object for each tile, like you do it in method1:

```
for (i=0; i<40; i++) {
  tiles[i] = { tileID: i}; // METHOD 1
}
```